# Visual Studio Code error when attempting to install support for Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.33.1, running in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)SL, and when i try Customize by installing support for Python, i get an error.

The message reads:

> "An unknown errror occurred. Please consult the log for more detials".

I don't know which log, or where it is, that this message mentions.

Can anyone help?

Note: i have reviewed the different suggestions presented as i tried to ask this question, but none were specific to Visual-studio-code.

Comment: Have you installed any packages in VScode?

Comment: no - the support for Python was the first thing i tried ... note, since posting this yesterday, i've received feed back from Whitewate Foundry (whose Pengwin is the WSL distro i'm running) that there are known issues w/ VS Code plug-ins. also - v1.34.0 came out and when installing that it actually suggested uninstalling from WSL and run it from Windows and the use a WSL extension to access all that is in WSL

Comment: VSCode has no language builtin but has extensions to allow you to run many programing languages. To run python you need to load some python extensions. the site https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=python&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance   will open the site for all VSCode extensions. Search on python and pick and choose the ones for you. Click on the tab at the top for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: sounds good; thanks again -- appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two locations for logs, one is Ctrl+Shift+P/F1 -> Developer: Show Logs. The second, where this more likely is, is Ctrl+Shift+I or Help -> Toggle Developer Tools and under the console there.

Comment: thanks b1lly - but proving my complete newbie-ness - are those keystorkes i should try from within VS COde or from the terminal command prompt?